# how to extend a constructor of a class in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, constructor, extension-methods

Suppose i have:

```
Public Class clsTest
   Public Sub New()
   End Sub

   Public Sub New(name_ As String)
      '...
   End Sub
End Class
```

I want to expand this class such:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Sub methodA(t1 As clsTest, i As Integer)
    '...
End Sub
```

But i can not extend constructor as:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Sub New(t1 As clsTest, name_ As String, i As Integer)
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [cannot extend constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782034/is-it-possible-to-create-constructor-extension-method-how) with an extension method. An extension method is nearly the same as a `static` (`shared` in VB) method that allows to write

```
instanceOfMyClass.SomeExtension(someParameter)
```

instead of

```
MyClass.SomeExtension(instanceOfMyClass, someParameter)
```

If you don't have acces to `clsTest`(you should really change your [**namings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)) but you want to extend it anyway, you could also create a new class that inherits from it:

```
Public Class Foo ' consider this as your clsTest
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Number As Int32
    Public Sub New(name As String)
        Me.Name = Name
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Bar
    Inherits Foo

    Public Sub New(name As String, i As Integer)
        MyBase.Name = name
        MyBase.Number = i
    End Sub
End Class
```

Finally, maybe you don't need to extend the class but you're just looking for a convenient way to initialize it in an one-liner:

```
Dim foo = New Foo("test") With {.Number = 4711}
```

Comment: Does exist another way? I cannot access `clsTest` but i want to extend it.

Comment: Yes, but is there any way without inheriting? (Extend Original Class) I want to use: `Dim t1 AS New clsTest("my name",2)` instead of `Dim t1 AS New Foo("my name",2)`.

Comment: @mohammadazadi: Edited my answer. Maybe you just need a one-liner.

Comment: @mohammadazadi: No your rep. is **8** ;-)